# Coffeescript property Error: Parse error on line 5: Unexpected '{

Tags: coffeescript

I have this code in Coffeescript

```
window.App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application
Models: {}
Collections: {}
Views: {}
Views.Layouts: {}
Routers: {}
```

And I'm trying to get this javascript code

```
window.App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application({
Models: {},
Collections: {},
Views: {},
Views.Layouts: {},
Routers: {}
});
```

I get this error: Error: Parse error on line 5: Unexpected '{

Comment: The first thing I'm noticing is that the fifth line has a `.` in it; the others don't.

Comment: It doesn't like the period, but I'm not sure why:   http://coffeescript.org/#try:window.App%20%3D%20new%20Backbone.Marionette.Application%0A%20%20Models%3A%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20Collections%3A%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20Views%3A%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20ViewsLayouts%3A%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20Routers%3A%20%7B%7D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
window.App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: 
      Layouts: {}
  Routers: {}
```